# C# WritePrivateProfileString() value other than English language

Tags: c#, .net, ini

I am trying to save a file path in **ini** file which contains a folder in Arabic language. i.e.

> D:\ملف جديد\Checking Folder

But after using `WritePrivateProfileString()` to write it in **settings.ini** . It shows path as follows:

> D:\??? ????\Checking Folder

What should I do to save the path correctly?

**Edit:**

Following is the code I am using to write ini file

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]

private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string val, string filePath);
```

Comment: What codepage is settings.ini on? Is it unicode?

Comment: I think it is unicode @Sefe

Comment: Are you using Win32 API? Can you put some code in your question?

Comment: @gsharp I edited my question

Comment: This isn't a good idea. Don't do it. These APIs can *only* write ANSI-encoded data to the file, unless you specifically create a UTF-8 file *first* and then open and write into it. In .NET, use an XML file, instead. There is built-in support for reading and writing XML files built into the .NET BCL.

Comment: @CodyGray I was able to successfully write in .ini file using Encoding.Default

Comment: Sure, it will "work". The problem happens when you change the code page or share the file with a system that uses a different code page. Then the data is unreadable and potentially corrupted. Oops. [Don't use Encoding.Default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2005/03/15/dont-use-encoding-default/); use UTF-8 or UTF-16. And that means you cannot use INI files.

Comment: @CodyGray I am now using UTF8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out [my INI library](https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini), I created it in order to have a friendlier (and more meaningful / intuitive) API then those WritePrivateProfile APIs.
Here is a sample of how you can use it:

```
// Your inputs.
string section, key, val, filePath;

var iniOptions = new IniOptions();
iniOptions.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

var ini = new IniFile(iniOptions);
ini.Load(filePath);

IniSection iniSection = ini.Sections[section];
IniKey iniKey = iniSection.Keys[key];
iniKey.Value = val;

ini.Save(filePath);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to write value in Arabic language by using:

Encoding.Default

& read it by using:

Encoding.UTF8

Comment: You should really use the same encoding for both reading and writing. Also I would suggest you to reconsider the usage of Encoding.Default because on different machines it can have different value. Also see the remarks of Encoding.Default property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I read the remarks, but when I try to write language (other than English) using UTF8 it stores the information in other characters

Comment: I thing the problem occurred because you were using "WritePrivateProfileString" instead of "WritePrivateProfileStringW".
Nevertheless you should use debugger in order to check what the value of Encoding.Default is on your machine and use it instead... You know that it's not UTF8, is it perhapse UTF-16LE?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Arabic")` for using Arabic Text in the path

Like for example if you want to read and write in the file than

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("YourFilePath", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Arabic")))
{
}

using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("YourFilePath", true, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Arabic")))
{
}
```

Comment: I think that should be `....StreamWriter("D:\SomePath\settings.ini", ...)` and then write the Arabic string into it.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @PeterB but we arent sure so I made it `YourFilePath` :D :)

Comment: But it will be restricting it to Arabic language only? @MohitShrivastava